# Pointcut for getting all beans in @Configuration class

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-aop

I use Spring Integration and have a flow described in some @Configuration annotated class (`@Bean` and `@Autowired` marked methods), f.e. CustomFlow.class.

If any element in flow throw exception I would like to intercept it with `@AfterThrowing` advice and do some actions (notification, write smth to DB, etc).

So the question is - how to write proper pointcut to get all beans in this case?

Comment: Line spaces to improve readability and code ticks to make it visible quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

@AfterThrowing(
 pointcut = "execution(*(..))",
 throwing= "error")
 public void logAfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable error) {
  //...
 }
}
```

and then the configuration:

```
<aop:after-throwing method="logAfterThrowing" throwing="error"   />
```

Comment: It seems **pointcut = "execution(* * *(..))"** isn't suitable for described case

Comment: @DmitriiAdonin sorry my mistake i made it write

Comment: Oh, nevermind, actually I didn't mark your answer "-1" if you mean it